# Ruby on rails: write correct unit test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading "Agile Web Development with Rails" and I can't understand a unit test.

There's a model defined like this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # .....
  validates :price, numericality: {greater_than_or_equal_to: 0.01}
  # .....
end
```

And the test:

```
  test "product price must be positive" do
    product = Product.new(
      title: "my title",
      description: "yyy",
      image_url: "zzz.jpg",
    )

    product.price = -1
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
      product.errors[:price]

    product.price = 0
    assert product.invalid?
    assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
      product.errors[:price]

    product.price = 1
    assert product.valid?

  end
```

Why would we need this:

```
    assert_equal ["must be greater than or equal to 0.01"],
      product.errors[:price]
```

Why compare error messages? Instead of writing a test like this:

```
product.price = -1
assert product.invalid?, "must be greater than or equal to 0.01"

product.price = 0
assert product.invalid?, "must be greater than or equal to 0.01"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood, the author of the book really wanted to verify that the  error message is the one he expected.

It seems to me a really bad idea to hardcode an error message, since it might be changed in the next framework version.

Comment: hardcode error message was just for beginners to graps it quickly. In that same chapter(7. TASK B:), author had changed this hard code message with: assert_equal [I18n.translate('errors.messages.taken')],
product.errors[:title]

Answer (score 0):

`object.errors` is a blank hash. When saving/updating an ActiveModel instance, if validation fails, the error will be added to specific key matching the attributes, like:

```
{ price: "must be...", name: "can't be blank", ...}.
```

In this case it's the "price" which failed validation. So the errors object is

```
{ price: "must be greater than or equal to 0.01"}
```

To access the message string. You need to the failed attribute as the key, like `errors[:price]`

Comment: Yeah I know about `object.errors` hash. I don't understand why do we need to compare values in it by `assert`? Instead, we should just set some invalid value and check if the object is invalid. If it is valid, then error message will be added to `object.errors`, and I don't understand why do we need to check this error text here (this text will anyway be echoed at the test stage)

Comment: @DmitryFrank, to judge if an object is invalid or not, the only way is to check if it has errors attribute and this attribute is not blank :)

Comment: Looks at source here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActiveModel/Validations/run_validations! This is the method `valid?` and `invalid?` depends on.

Comment: no, to judge if an object is invalid or not, there is special predicate method:  `object.invalid?`

Comment: Yes, if you following through the source of `invalid?` inside, you'll finally reach `run_validations!`, which will check if `errors` is empty. For the above url, please add "!" after it, SO can't include it in url.

Comment: Ok, well, it seems author just wanted to verify if error message is what he expects or not. To me, it seems not so good solution: what if in the next rails version this message will be changed a bit? Assert will not pass then.

Comment: I think that's a question about taste of style. I think the tests are fine and not so likely to broke. Of course you can also check if `match` some words, that's more robust, and I use this style often.